# HTTP vs HTTPS Azure storage connection from worker role

Tags: security, azure, storage

Azure worke role, working with sensitive data, but performance is important. Same geo-location and affinity group.

When connecting to Azure storage, should I use HTTPS? Or is HTTP secure enough since, since it's all inside Azure?

In other words, is communication between Worker role and storage server happening on internal network? Or is it going through Internet, can be intercepted and I need to use HTTPS to secure data transmitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the storage account is in the same data center as the worker role, the traffic goes over a local network, and it should be safe from eavesdropping.

Comment: How can I know if it's in the same datacenter? Even on the westcoast they might have several datacenters (not sure about Azure geographical layout).

Comment: If you choose a location (e.g. US West), and it's the same location for both your hosted service and your storage account, it's the same data center.

Comment: So, the only reason to use HTTPS between service and storage would be if I choose to place them in different geographical regions?

Comment: I suppose HTTPS could be part of a defense-in-depth strategy. If a breach gave someone access to your virtual network, HTTPS could still protect this traffic from eavesdropping.